# xcode 6.2 cannot install old simulator by coping

Tags: xcode, installation, simulator

everyone.

I found that I cannot install old simulator into Xcode 6.2 by coping now. I tried to download the 7.1 simulator in Xcode, but always get a no response message. Is there another way to install iOS 7.1 simulator for Xcode 6.2?

Thanks.

Comment: I am downloading iOS 7.1 simulator in Xcode now. The progress bar in the Download window does not update itself at all. :( So I thought the downloading did not start. Then I found the main window of Xcode show the correct progress. Hope the downloading can be finished successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads

Starting with Xcode 6.2, it will install to /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes rather than in the Xcode.app bundle itself.  This allows you to install the legacy runtimes without breaking the signature of the app bundle (which in turn allows you to download delta updates from the store rather than full downloads when updating Xcode.app) and allows them to persist across Xcode.app updates.

Comment: I have an iMac and a MacBook. If I have downloaded simulator on one. How can I copy it to another one?

Comment: That is a different question, but FWIW, I'd just use rsync.

Comment: I cannot find Profiles in /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/. I can only find Devices there.

Comment: @Jassi Devices are stored in $HOME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices ... You're looking at the wrong path.

Comment: I am checking it in $HOME.

Comment: @Jassi Exactly.  That is your problem.  You need to look in /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices ... you were looking in $HOME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices